# Tumblr posts cycling between two different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make it so that the container around a particular post is a different color than the one adjacent to it. Basically, the the containers just need to cycle between two different colors.

[image: Left is current, right is what I require]

Left side is how it currently looks, right is how I want it to look. Thanks!

**CSS**

```
#content {
  float:left;
  width:800px;
  padding:25px;
  top:-50px; left:45px;
  background:transparent;
  {block:PermalinkPage}
  width:300px;
  {/block:PermalinkPage}
}

.entry {
  width:150px;
  margin:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#336136;
  margin-left:-12px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  padding:12px;
  {block:PermalinkPage}
  width:250px;
  margin-left:40px;
  {/block:PermalinkPage} 
}

.entry:nth-child(odd) {
background: #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  {block:Posts}
  <div class="entry">

  {miscellaneous_blocks_here}

  </div>
  {/block:Posts}
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code here so future users can access it even if other sites move their content

Answer (score 5):

Why not use CSS3 selectors and forgo the javascript dance?

```
.entry:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
}

.entry:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ff003d
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: @Claudiu correct, but its a far better solutions if the OP doesn't need to support IE8.

Comment: @Claudiu If people are still using IE8 their computer needs to be shot in order to force them to update to the modern world.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't left a comment when you downvoted me. This is my first day when I'm posting answers and I want feedback. @RevanProdigalKnight I agree

Comment: @Claudiu Reversed. After editing the OPs question, I realised my downvote was in haste, as you answered what they asked for. :D

Comment: That's a much better solution. I didn't work quite right when I copy/pasted, though. I ended up removing the second half of your solution and set a background color in the original(.entry) It worked perfect after that! Thanks to the both of you. Edited the OP with those changes

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to use classes and ids. For each class that you want this feature you can increment your id by one:

```
$('.your_class_for_each_item').each(function(){
        i++;
            var newID='your_id'+i;
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
        $(this).val(i);
    });
```

This will result in newID1, newID2 etc. Then for odd ids use a color and for even ids another color. You use a function like this:

```
function(){
  if(i%2==0){ //check if the number is odd
    var z = document.getElementById('newID');
    z.setAttribute('style','background:color_for_even_numbers');
  }
  else{
   z.setAttribute('style','background:color_for_odd_numbers');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant seem to get it working. Do I need to create a new ID or am I able to use one that was there previously (#content)? I edited the Script into the post.

Comment: Why are you using style tags for javascript content? javascript uses <script></script> tags. You don't need to create a new id. Also you need to integrate that javascript into the code so that when an item is added the function is called. a link to your site could help